# Til, Till or 'Til? Which one should I use?

Tags: word-choice

Til, Till or 'Til?
Which one should I use if I want to say in a letter:

(Until) next time!

Comment: [*Until* is historically derived from *till*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=until&searchmode=none), rather than the other way around.  That means nothing is omitted in *till*, so the apostrophe isn't appropriate.  (Unless you reinterpret *till* as an abbreviated form of *until*, but I think that's perceived as nonstandard.)

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't apparently been asked here on ELL before, but it [has been asked on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/)

Comment: It is not a question of "should". There is nothing with using the word *until*.

Comment: I suppose it depends on who you ask, but it appears that [until](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until%2Ctill%2Ctil&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctil%3B%2Cc0) surpassed [till](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until%2Ctill&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctill%3B%2Cc0) in the mid-19th century. And *til* dropped in popularity quite a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Question is answered by @sbailboat in the comments. "Until" and "till" are both acceptable, as "until" is derived from "till." "Til" and "'til" are incorrect.

Comment: From the Free Dictionary:  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/till
*"Usage Note: Till and until are generally interchangeable in both writing and speech, though as the first word in a sentence until is usually preferred . . ."*